# How to call setup once for all tests and teardown after all are finished

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a bunch of tests written using pytest. There are all under a directory `dir`. For example:

```
dir/test_base.py
dir/test_something.py
dir/test_something2.py
...
```

The simplified version of code in them is as follows:

`test_base.py`

```
import pytest

class TestBase:
   def setup_module(module):
      assert False

   def teardown_module(module):
      assert False
```

`test_something.py`

```
import pytest
from test_base import TestBase

class TestSomething(TestBase):
   def test_dummy():
       pass
```

`test_something2.py`

```
import pytest
from test_base import TestBase

class TestSomethingElse(TestBase):
   def test_dummy2():
       pass
```

All my `test_something*.py` files extend the base class in `test_base.py`. Now I wrote `setup_module(module)` and `teardown_module(module)` methods in `test_base.py`. I was expecting the setup_module to be called once for all tests, and `teardown_module()` to be called at the end, once all tests are finished.

But the functions don’t seem to be getting called? Do I need some decorators for this to work?

Answer (score 25):

The OP's requirement was for setup and teardown each to execute only **once**, not one time per module. This can be accomplished with a combination of a `conftest.py` file, `@pytest.fixture(scope="session")` and passing the fixture name to each test function.

These are described in the [Pytest fixtures documentation](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixtures)

Here's an example:

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
    def my_setup(request):
        print '\nDoing setup'
        def fin():
            print ("\nDoing teardown")
        request.addfinalizer(fin)
```

**test_something.py**

```
def test_dummy(my_setup):
    print '\ntest_dummy'
```

**test_something2.py**

```
def test_dummy2(my_setup):
    print '\ntest_dummy2'

def test_dummy3(my_setup):
    print '\ntest_dummy3'
```

The output when you run py.test -s:

```
collected 3 items 

test_something.py 
Doing setup

test_dummy
.
test_something2.py 
test_dummy2
.
test_dummy3
.
Doing teardown
```

The name `conftest.py` matters: you can't give this file a different name and expect Pytest to find it as a source of fixtures.

Setting `scope="session"` is important. Otherwise setup and teardown will be repeated for each test module.

If you'd prefer not to pass the fixture name *my_setup* as an argument to each test function, you can place test functions inside a class and apply the `pytest.mark.usefixtures` decorator to the class.

Answer (score 15):

Put `setup_module` and `teardown_module` outside of a class on module level. Then add your class with your tests.

```
def setup_module(module):
    """..."""

def teardown_module(module):
    """..."""

class TestSomething:

    def test_dummy(self):
        """do some tests"""
```

For more info refer to [this article](http://agiletesting.blogspot.com/2005/01/python-unit-testing-part-3-pytest-tool.html).

Comment: are those permitted in `conftest.py` files?

Comment: @jxramos based on my testing, they are not. You could place them in your __init__.py file in your test suite directory though.

Answer (score 1):

setup_module/teardown_module are called for the module where the eventual (derived) tests are defined.  This also allows to customize the setup.  If you only ever have one setup_module you can put it to test_base.py and import it from the other places. HTH.

Comment: i edited my qsn about to show my code. Is this what you mean? because, that doesn't work...

Comment: setup_module needs to be defined at module level, not class level.

Comment: hi @hpk42 what does that mean exactly? sorry, i'm a python noob.

Comment: "module-level" means at indentation level 0 in your file (same level where you define the class).  You currently define setup_module within the class definition.

Answer (score -1):

First of all it is a good practice to put all tests in a module called "tests":

```
<product>
   ...
   tests/
      __init__.py
      test_something.py
```

Secondly I think you should use setup_class/teardown_class methods in your base class:

```
import unittest
class MyBase(unittest.TestCase):

   @classmethod
   def setup_class(cls):
       ...

   @classmethod
   def teardown_class(cls):
       ...
```

More info: http://pytest.org/latest/xunit_setup.html

Comment: Is there a reason this answer doesn't address specifically his trouble using the document-defined **Module level setup/teardown**. Are you suggesting the `setup_module(module)` / `teardown_module(module)` functions do not work as documented?

Comment: Im just asking if you are implying that those documented methods do not work, as suggested by your answer to do it in the __init__ instead. Thats all. Because even in your link, you reference to the doc that explains to use those methods, which are broken for the OP

Comment: Hi @GiacomoSpettoli thanks for your reply. I am actually looking for getting setup_module/teardown_module to work, instead of setup_class/teardown_class. Because, I want these to be invoked only once for all tests. setup_class/teardown_class will be called for each of my tests that derive my base class. HTH

Comment: I see...so you should try to put those methods in the __ init __.py. That was my first answer but I changed it because, without your last constraint, the use of class methods looked cleaner.